# Query MongoDB nested Array of arrays for based on multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
  'id' : 1,
  'properties':{
    'type': [[0.05, 'education'],[0.6, 'health'],[0.9, 'math']]
  }
},
{
  'id' : 1,
  'properties':{
    'type': [[0.05, 'education'],[0.01, 'health'],[0.9, 'math']]
  }
},
```

How could you query based on two value parameters in nested array of arrays? Goal would be to return the 1st document with `properties.type[0] > 0.5`, and `properties.type[1] == 'health'`.

Have tried the following query with no luck.

```
db.collection.find({'properties.type': {'$elemMatch':{'$elemMatch':{'$all': [{ "$gt": 0.5, "$lt": 1 },'health']}}}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here please try this, I use `$unwind` and `$arrayElemAt`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$properties.type"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$expr": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$properties.type",
                  0
                ]
              },
              0.5
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$expr": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$properties.type",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "health"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

**Updated**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orignalObj": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$properties.type"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$expr": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$properties.type",
                  0
                ]
              },
              0.5
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$expr": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$properties.type",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "health"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$orignalObj"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hello @Omar, thanks for the response, the query works, however it currently only returns `[0.6, 'health']` instead of `[[0.05, 'education'],[0.6, 'health'],[0.9, 'math']]` for `properties.type`. Is there a way to return the document unchanged?

Comment: Yes, that can also be done I'll update my answer